# Mocking NSWindowController

Tags: macos, ocmock

I have a Mac application, an NSStatusItem really, in which I'm trying to test its preferences window.
 I used this code as a model since it works much like my code except that my window is initialized and display in a function other than applicationDidFinishLaunching.
http://bit.ly/wH6QOk

I get the error:
Expected method not invoked: window

I can't figure out why this happens. Here is my test code:

```
-(void)testPreferencesInit {    
    mockWindowController = [OCMockObject mockForClass:[NSWindowController class]];
    id mockWindow = [OCMockObject mockForClass:[NSWindow class]];

    [[[mockWindowController expect] andReturn:mockWindow] window];
    [[mockWindow expect] makeKeyAndOrderFront:weathervane];

    [weathervane showPreferences:nil];

    [mockWindowController verify];
    [mockWindow verify];

    id windowController;
    object_getInstanceVariable(weathervane, "windowController", (void **)&windowController);
    GHAssertEqualObjects(windowController, mockWindowController,
                                @"windowController not set on appDelegate");
    GHAssertTrue([[windowController windowNibName] isEqualToString:@"Preferences"], @"Window Controller nib name not set");

    object_setInstanceVariable(weathervane, "windowController", nil);
    mockWindowController = nil;
}
```

Comment: Can you post your `showPreferences` implementation?

Comment: Here it is: `-(IBAction)showPreferences:(id)sender{
    
   
    [[windowController window] makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear from your code how you expect the `windowController` to point to `mockWindowController`. Have you implemented the category initializer and `invokeSupersequent` code as in Matt Gallagher's post?

It appears from your code that `windowController` is a property of your weathervane class. I think the simplest approach would be to eschew trying to override `NSWindowController`'s initialization and just pass your mock into your controller:

```
-(void)testPreferencesInit {    
    mockWindowController = [OCMockObject mockForClass:[NSWindowController class]];
    id mockWindow = [OCMockObject mockForClass:[NSWindow class]];

    [[[mockWindowController expect] andReturn:mockWindow] window];
    [[mockWindow expect] makeKeyAndOrderFront:weathervane];

    weathervane.windowController = mockWindowController;

    [weathervane showPreferences:nil];

    [mockWindowController verify];
    [mockWindow verify];
}
```

Comment: Yes, I did. The only difference between his and my code (AFAICT) is that his code calls applicationDidFinishLaunching whereas mine calls showPreferences.

Comment: Well, you could step through the code in a debugger, and find out where it's falling apart. But it's a very complex solution that you're likely to sink a lot of time into. I think it's much simpler to just inject the mock window controller at test time.